# select with MD5 + CONCAT using where

Tags: mysql, md5, concatenation

Where problem ?
select work fine.. when check in where - give error
Unknown column 'confirm' in 'where clause'

```
 SELECT 
    users_id, MD5(CONCAT(users_pass, users_email)) AS confirm
FROM
    (users_items) 
WHERE users_active = 0 
    AND confirm = '39a5eccb97f63a2bb649ddd95c5a3ba7' 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: is there a column called "confirm" in the table "users_items"? If so, try surrounding it with back-ticks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

because confirm is an `alias`.

You can't use an `alias` in the `where` clause in *the same level of query*.

You have to do

```
where xxx
and MD5(CONCAT(users_pass, users_email)) = '39a5eccb97f63a2bb649ddd95c5a3ba7'
```

Or, as stated by Vatev, you can use an alias in an `HAVING` clause. But use an `HAVING` clause may have an impact on performance.

Cause where filters your query (trying to use indexes, for example), and the HAVING clause is filtering on these filtered datas.

```
where xxx
HAVING confirm = '39a5eccb97f63a2bb649ddd95c5a3ba7'
```

Comment: Or `HAVING confirm = '39a5eccb97f63a2bb649ddd95c5a3ba7' `.

Comment: Is it possible to use HAVING without GROUP BY? I think not.

Comment: @Bandydan in mysql at least, yes.

Comment: As it is said in documentation, "Do not use HAVING for items that should be in the WHERE clause". I trust those guys, so I won't :)

Comment: Yes. WHERE MD5 most recent query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    users_id,
    MD5(CONCAT(users_pass, users_email)) AS confirm
FROM
    (users_items) 
WHERE
    users_active = 0 
    AND MD5(CONCAT(users_pass, users_email)) = '39a5eccb97f63a2bb649ddd95c5a3ba7'
LIMIT 1
```

As for HAVING clause, AFAIK, it is used only with GROUP BY.

Added:

"In general, clauses used must be given in exactly the order shown in the syntax description. For example, a HAVING clause must come after any GROUP BY clause and before any ORDER BY clause."

"Do not use HAVING for items that should be in the WHERE clause. For example, do not write the following:

```
SELECT col_name FROM tbl_name HAVING col_name > 0;
```

Write this instead:

```
SELECT col_name FROM tbl_name WHERE col_name > 0;"
```

These are quotations from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html.